# NHibernate: How to load only specific properties in a list of entities (instead of full object)?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have been using NHibernate in my project and it is working very good until the time.
Now I am facing one problem and don't know how to solve it.

Problem is I want to fetch only x columns from table instead of all and then bind this to original entity with fetched columns assigned values where for others should show null.

e.g. I have table Employee as 
FieldName DataType
ID        int
FName     nvarchar(500)
LName     nvarchar(500)
Resume    nvarchar(max)

From above I want to fetch only Id, FName, LName only and bind it to Employee entity and then we would like to load Resume by making separate database call using NHibernate.

I tried

```
var list = session
    .CreateCriteria(typeof (Employee))
    .SetProjection(Projections
                       .ProjectionList()
                       .Add(Projections.Property("Id"))
                       .Add(Projections.Property("FName"))
                       .Add(Projections.Property("LName")))
    .List();
```

but above code returns restricted column data but in form of array of object.
I wanted this to get bind to entity instead of object array.
So, please share your thoughts on this

Comment: You can do this, but from a object oriented point of view, it's not a goo idea. The resulting Employee instances are not really Empoyees, e.g. changes wouldn't be persisted. In your service classes (where your business logic resides) you should never mix the real, session bound Employees with the projected Employees. Because of that, it should be another class.

Comment: Did you know that you can specify properties to be lazy loaded? It means that they are separately loaded, only when they are accessed. This works well if a property contains a huge amount of data. For trivial amount of data, I wouldn't bother to load it all. Accessing the table is expensive, loading the data usually not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `ResultTransformer` and call `ToList()` with the type, otherwise NHibernate didn't know what to do with the projections. And you need also to specifiy the target property names in your Employee type.
Your query can look simething like this:

```
var list = session
    .CreateCriteria(typeof (Employee))
    .SetProjection(Projections
                   .ProjectionList()
                   .Add(Projections.Property("Id"), "Id")
                   .Add(Projections.Property("FName"), "FirstName")
                   .Add(Projections.Property("LName"), "LastName"))
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Employee>())
    .List<Employee>();
```

**Please note:** "Id", "FirstName" and "LastName" must be properties in the `Employee` type.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [@Rabban](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53338582/5779732) explains it well; +1 to him. I am just putting it differently.

As you observed, `SetProjection` will return array of objects. To convert objects to entities, you need to call `SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Entity>()`. The code sample is already given in other answer; I will not repeat it.

Problem with your current code is that, you need to type in column names as *string*. I generally avoid this approach. I prefer to use strongly typed version of same with `IQueryOver` as below:

```
public IList<TEntity> GetList<TEntity>(ProjectionList columnList, Junction where, int top) where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    IQueryOver<TEntity> query = null;
    if((columnList != null) && (where != null))
    {
        query = session.QueryOver<TEntity>()
                .Select(columnList)
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<TEntity>())
                .Where(where);
    }
    else if((columnList != null) && (where == null))
    {
        query = session.QueryOver<TEntity>()
                .Select(columnList)
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<TEntity>());
    }
    else if((columnList == null) && (where != null))
    {
        query = session.QueryOver<TEntity>()
                .Where(where);
    }
    else
    {
        query = session.QueryOver<TEntity>();
    }

    IList<TEntity> result = query.Take(top).List();
    return result;
}
```

You can pass strongly typed list of columns to this method as below:

```
ProjectionList columnList = Projections.ProjectionList();
columnList.Add(Projections.Property<Employee>(x => x.Id));
...
...
```